# Recurring ASP.NET 5 RC1 DNX error in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Every time I start Visual Studio I get the following error when opening an ASP.NET 5 project:

[image]

Then I close Visual Studio, reopen it, open my project and I don't get that error anymore ...

What is strange is I always the error when I first open an ASP.NET 5 project which forces me to restart Visual Studio ... Why?

How to fix this?